# Datatable and Stacked Bar Chart in One Visualization using ggvis, ggplot2 or googleVis

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggvis, googlevis, dt

I would like to create a datatable with a bar chart in one visualization in r.  I have created something similar in the DT library, but I am not sure if I have the ability to create a stacked bar in DT and the chart doesn't look quite as good as using ggplot2 or any of the other libraries specifically for visualizations (right orientation is one of the issues).

Here is what I was able to create in DT:
[image: DT]

Comment: Please show your code, along with a data sample that works with your code.

Comment: Yep.

**data:**
    `a <- c("1","2","3","4","5") 
    b <- c(9,20,17,14,18) 
    dataexample <- cbind(a,b)`

**code:**
    `datatable(dataexample) %>%
    formatStyle(
    'b',
    background = styleColorBar(b, 'steelblue'),
    backgroundSize = '100% 90%',
    backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition = 'center')`